# Clear the contents of each row in a column on one sheet, depending on the change in a column on the same row on another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm struggling with this code, which works perfectly inside the same sheet, to get it work between two sheets. For an example if I change a content in cell E5 or in multiple cells in E column on "Sheet1", this clears a content in Cell A5 or in multiple cells in A column, depending on the row they are in.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  // Check if column E and sheet "Sheet1"
  if(range.getColumn() == 5 && range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet1") 
  {
    if(range.getHeight()>1)
    {
      // Multiple cells selection case
      var nbRow = range.getNumRows();
      var i;
      for(i =0; i < nbRow; i++)
      {
        var temp = row + i;
        e.source.getRange("A"+temp).clear();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // One cell selection case
      e.source.getRange("A"+row).clear();
    }
  } 
}
```

Could any of you guys please help me with the code to get it work between two sheets, because it's already driving me crazy :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change in one sheet clears range in another sheet**

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==5) {
    var sh2=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    sh2.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,1).clearContent()  
  }
}
```

Question: What should I do to the code so it starts on the fifth row?  First four rows are frozen. (Probably header info)

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart>4) {
    var sh2=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    sh2.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,1).clearContent()  
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Cooper and what should I add to the code to start with fifth row? First four rows are frozen and are not included in this code..